# tcpServer: How to send something and close the TCP connection afterwards

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

I am using `tcpServer` given here in my C# app:-

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488668/Csharp-TCP-Server

It has a `TcpServer` class which can open a port and start listening on it. I receive data through `OnDataAvailable` event handler provided by `TcpServer` class. The problem is, that the **client expects and depends on tcp server to close the connection**.

Before closing the connection, (conditionally) **I want to send some data back to the client**.
Here is what I have written in order to achieve the same.

```
static void myServer_OnDataAvailable(TcpServerConnection connection)
{
    //...Some code...
    connection.sendData(someText);
    if (connection.verifyConnected())
    {
        connection.forceDisconnect();
    }
}
```

Now, when I execute this code, it closes the connection before sending text to the client.

Please help me figure out how can I achieve the same.

Comment: The problem is, when I execute this code, it closes the connection before sending text to the client.

Comment: Do you want to close the connection normally or do you want to force the client to disconnect abnormally?

Comment: Closing the connection normally is definitely preferable

Comment: Then why are you calling `forceDisconnect` instead of closing the connection normally?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
static void myServer_OnDataAvailable(TcpServerConnection connection)
{
    //...Some code...
    connection.sendData(someText);
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    if (connection.verifyConnected())
    {
        connection.forceDisconnect();
    }
}
```

Comment: Will 2 seconds be enough? I was searching for an event, on which I can close the connection.